# Is there a way to know whether an email is successfully relayed with C#?

Tags: c#, email, c#-2.0

Is there a way to know whether an email is successfully relayed with C# ?

I am using System.Net.Mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set MailMessage's DeliveryNotificationOptions propert to
[`System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/siva/archive/2008/03/14/sending-emails-with-delivery-receipt-notification.aspx);

or try :

```
static void ReadReceipts()
{
//create the mail message
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

//set the addresses
mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com");

//set the content
mail.Subject = "This is an email";
mail.Body = "this is the body content of the email.";

//To request a read receipt, we need add a custom header named 'Disposition-Notification-To'
//in this example, read receipts will go back to 'someaddress@mydomain.com'
//it's important to note that read receipts will only be sent by those mail clients that 
//a) support them
//and
//b)have them enabled.
mail.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "<someaddress@mydomain.com>");


//send the message
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: Can I set multiple DeliveryNotificationOptions? Thanks.

Comment: Many servers - particularly corporate ones - block delivery reports, as they reveal which email addresses are valid and can therefore contribute to spam.

Answer (score 2):

Only way to know if someone has received an email is to ask them to let you know in some way (read reciept or similar).

Which is why all the email confirmation schemes always have that you need to click on a link to confirm that it's your email.

Comment: That's ok, but sometimes while registration if the user doesn't get a confirmation email (an email with a link to activate the account), how can we know about that, because I don't get any exception from the SmtpClient class methods.

Comment: There's no way you can know if they've received it, even if it sends fine from your servers it might get lost anywhere on the way (including that his email provider might have blacklisted your email provider for some reason and automatically deletes all emails). I suggest that after the user register you show a message to the effect `"if you've not received an email within x minutes, please check your spam folder, or try to re-send the message, or re-send the message to an alternative email address"`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a service such as [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com), which allows you to send via smtp or an api and can notify your app of failed messages using a web hook.

Postmark use [PowerMTA](http://www.port25.com), an email gateway capable of detecting junk marking, bounces etc. You can go direct through PowerMTA, but Postmark wrap it all up nicely.